# Why must a mutable reference be used in the for loop here?

Tags: rust

This is probably a silly question, but this is kinda making me crazy. I have this simple code:

```
let args = env::args();
println!("num args read: {}", args.len());

for element in args {
   println!("{}", element);
}

let arg_string: String = args.collect();
```

This doesn't work and gives the error:

```
    |
4   |     let args = env::args();
    |         -------- move occurs because `args` has type `std::env::Args`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
8   |     for element in args {
    |                    ----
    |                    |
    |                    `args` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
    |                    help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&args`
...
14  |     let arg_string: String = args.collect();
    |                              ^^^^ value used here after move
```

This makes sense as the `into_iter()` call consumes `self`. So I try to modify the for-loop to `for element in &args` and I get this error:

```
9 |     for element in &args {
  |                    -^^^^
  |                    |
  |                    `&std::env::Args` is not an iterator
  |                    help: consider removing the leading `&`-reference
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::env::Args`
  = note: `std::iter::Iterator` is implemented for `&mut std::env::Args`, but not for `&std::env::Args`
  = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

Why can't I iterate over a reference over a iterator? I found out that I can do

```
let mut args = env::args();
println!("num args read: {}", args.len());

for element in &mut args {
   println!("{}", element);
}

let arg_string: String = args.collect();
```

and this gets rid of the compiler error. Why must I take a mutable reference here instead of just a reference?

Comment: You get owned `String`s on demand from the iterator, but I actually don’t know why they can’t be `&'static str`.

Comment: Consider creating a Vec first `let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();`. As @kmdreko mentioned, `env::args()` returns an iterator, which needs to keep some mutable internal pointers when you do the for-loop.

Comment: FWIW, the reason (well, one reason) `Args` is an iterator instead of an array of `&'static str` is because different platforms have different ways of accessing arguments. Not all of them necessarily give immutable pointers to UTF-8 encoded strings in static memory. The `Args` interface is about as general as it can possibly get.

Comment: @trentcl I actually think no common OS guarantees that the command-line arguments are valid UTF-8. In that sense `Args` definitely isn't as general as it can possibly get, but `ArgsOs` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `Args` like it is a *collection*, but it isn't; its an *iterator*. Your `&mut` workaround satisfies the compiler but doesn't actually do what you want. The for-loop will *exhaust* the iterator meaning the `args.collect()` won't yield any values.

The fix is to call `env::args()` separately for each usage. <s>You aren't saving anything by trying to use the same variable.</s> I forgot that `Args` creates owned `String`s, so you might be better off collecting the args into a `Vec` first if you need to iterate over it multiple times.

Comment: I understand your comment, but I still don't understand why I can't loop over `&args`. There's a comment saying that `args` is an iterator but is that saying that you can't iterate over borrowed iterators?

Comment: Basically. Iteration requires calling `next()` repeatedly on an iterator, which mutates it. So in order to iterate with a borrowed iterator, you'd need a new iterator. You *could* get a new iterator via `clone()` but the for loop won't do it for you... and in this case it isn't even an option, because `Args` doesn't implement `Clone`.